# How do I construct an authenticated HTTP request in Postman?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I have Drupal 7 installed locally on my computer with the domain set to http://drupal.local.

I am trying to prepare an external script in PHP or Python (or even in pure Bash using curl, if it does not require a lot of extra work), which will successfully execute an HTTP request by default available only for the logged in user.

To understand what such a HTTP request should look like, I am first trying to perform such a HTTP request using Postman, but all my attempts failed.

This is what I've done so far:

1. In the browser, I logged in as administrator of the Drupal 7 site
2. I opened the browser on http://drupal.local/en/node/add/article and I received status 200 (The page is displayed correctly in my browser.)
3. In Postman I set:

   - request method on: GET
   - URL: http://drupal.local/en/node/add/article
   - Headers: I set all headers identically to those in the browser including the current cookies containing the session key with its value
4. I don't have access to this page and I receive a 403 error

How do I construct an authenticated HTTP request in Postman that will work for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Token authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/tokenauth) but be careful:

From module description:

> Be careful with what paths you expose to Token Authentication, as it is effectively a very simple, very low security password mechanism. You can expose Administration pages through bad configuration.

1. Install / enable Token authentication Module.
2. Go to *admin/config/services/tokenauth*
3. Add the path you want to give access to with token.
   [image]
   in the example below i added all add content pages.
4. Go to *admin/people* edit the user you want to generate token.
5. Generate Token by clicking on `Token authentication` tab it will give a token for that user like `?token=tuvj7cMwauxStWGVQYfo`.
6. Then you can use it with postman.
   [image]

**Note:** it may not be the best way.